# How to do error tracking with firebase analytics for specific user?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I want to track when an error happened - the user clicks  BUTTON AND nothing happens ( this kind of error )
I am using [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started) and can log an event with usr_id also.
Now I want to filter specific userId all the events with a timestamp. I have not yet found out in the documentation.
How can I ACHIEVE THIS?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to filter events with user_id in Firebase. You could consider linking your Firebase project with BigQuery, which allows you to export the raw, unsampled event data along with the user_id.

To [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) to BigQuery:

1. Click the Settings icon, then select Project Settings.
2. On the Project Settings page, click the Integrations tab.
3. On the BigQuery card, click Link.

Comment: yes you are correct, Thanks. 
My teammate said that bigquery is costly, for my case I had used FirebaseCrashlytics.recordException and I can have details in the log.
Will check about BigQuery more .